# SwiftSupport folder when building Jenkins WatchKit app

Tags: swift, jenkins, build-process, watchkit, xcode6.3

I have an Objective-C project that I have built a WatchKit app for using Swift as I though it would be a good entry point to learning a bit of Swift. The build process we have is using Jenkins using the build script to create the IPA structure.

I have found guides online stating the Structure of the IPA needed and have the script create and copy the correct files to create the WatchKitSupport folder. When I compare the contents of the IPA generated from the Archive through Xcode with the one from the build script it has a folder in called SwiftSupport.

The IPA SwiftSupport (when built through Xcode) contains 9 dylib files. How can I in the build script create this folder? Is it just a case or directly copying them from the location they reside in Xcode (which doesn't make for a very reusable portion of the build script) or is there a more robust simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When archiving an app the .xcarchive contains a SwiftSupport folder with those .dylib files. You can use this folder when creating your .ipa.

Just make sure the SwiftSupport folder is a sibling of the Payload folder in the .ipa, otherwise you will get an 'Invalid Swift Support' error in iTunes Connect.